# converting one column to factor works, many doesn't (using dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

got a huge dataframe I want to conver char columns to factor:

If I get column by column this way Works:

```
df$column1 <- as.factor(df$column1)

class(df$column1)
[1] "factor"
```

If I try to automate the proces, not going column by column, this way don't:

```
   library(magrittr)
   library(dplyr)    

    df <-  df %>%  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)


There were 450 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
4: In mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
```

I know there's other methods to accomplish it but the issue is I need it to be done using dplyr::mutate_if because all the wrangling is inside pipes

[EDITED]

```
> str(df)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 583860 obs. of  450 variables:
 $ column1                                : chr  "NJEWE000147" "ERTTYF000147" "WTFD000318" "WEERRESD001112" ...
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example  Not getting any warnings with `df <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:5], col2 = LETTERS[1:5], col3 = rnorm(5), stringsAsFactors= FALSE);
 df %>%  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% str#'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col3: num  0.0129 1.3046 -2.371 0.4848 -1.0348`

Comment: Works fine for me (`iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species); iris %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% str()`

Comment: your columns probably are not character. What is the output of `str(df)` ?

Comment: Due to condifentiality issues no part of real data can be shared here. In addition, dataframe is more tan 400 columns and thousands rows long. I've tested with dummy data, working. The issue I try to resolve is the warning message. Seems to have a problem in conversión step I can't resolve. Updated question with str output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar case happened to me. Not really a clue of the reason but solved converting to data frame

```
df <- data.frame(df)
```

Try and tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today and I think I figured out the cause. Your data frame is grouped, that's why factor conversion is off - it's converting the vector on a group-by-group basis. Converting to a regular old data frame solves this problem, because it removes the grouping. All the comments saying they cannot replicate the issue are not using grouped data frames.

So if you're trying to solve it in a pipe, simply use `ungroup()`.